# Adding custom attribute to WooCommerce shop loop product title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am attempting to add a custom attribute to the WooCommerce loop. Currently I have the following in my functions file

```
function cc_template_loop_product_custom_attribute()
{
    $abv = $product->get_attribute('pa_alcohol-by-volume');
    if (!empty($abv))
    {
        echo get_attribute('pa_alcohol-by-volume');
    };
}

add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'cc_template_loop_product_title', 10);
```

The intention is to get display the attribute 'Alcohol by volume' after the product title. However this is not working and basically causing the loop to stop rendering as soon as it reaches the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `get_attribute()` directly will throw an error like

> Call to undefined function get_attribute()

So use it in this way

```
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'wh_insertAfterShopProductTitle', 15);

function wh_insertAfterShopProductTitle()
{
    global $product;

    $abv = $product->get_attribute('pa_alcohol-by-volume');
    if (empty($abv))
        return;
    echo __($abv, 'woocommerce');
}
```

*Code goes in [`functions.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*
**Code is tested and works.**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, that's pointed me in the right direction, I needed to add some extra mark-up to out put on the page.